# Why can multiparty Schnorr signatures not be solved for linearly?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

If you only need the notation skim down to the bold line.
Quoting from [en.bitcoin.it](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Schnorr)

> Schnorr signatures are a proposed future extension that give a new way
>   to generate signatures r, s on a hash h.
>
> Given a hash value h, hash function f(), private key x, group
>   generator G, and public key P=xG, we can generate a Schnorr signature
>   on h as follows:
>
> Choose a random nonce k. Let R=Gk, and let s = k - f(h . R . P)x. The
>   Schnorr signature is the pair (R, s). Note that R is a public key, so
>   would require 33 bytes to represent (32 bytes + 1 bit indicating
>   "even" vs "odd").
>
> To check the validity of a signature (R, s) against a public key P, do
>   the following:
>
> Note that sG = (k- f(h . R . P))G = kG - f(h . R . P)xG = R - f(h . R
>   . P)P. So we simply compare sG + f(h . R . P)P to R to check the
>   signature.
>
> An advantage of this method is that, if parties cooperate, we can
>   generate a single signature that validates two or more separate
>   transactions.
>
> Choose h1, h2, x1, x2, G, P1=Gx1, P2=Gx2. Each party chooses a nonce
>   yielding k1 and k2, and publicly shares R1=Gk1, R2=Gk2.
>
> Let R = R1+R2. **Each signer generates an s, s1 = k1 - f(h . R . P)x1,
>   s2 = k2 - f(h . R . P)x2.** The signature (R, s) where s = s1 + s2
>   proves both transactions are signed.
>
> Note that sG = (s1 + s2)G = s1G + s2G = (k1 - f(h . R . P)x1)G + (k2 -
>   f(h . R . P)x2)G = k1G - f(h . R . P)x1G + k2G - f(h . R . P)x2G = R1
>   + R2 - f(h . R . P)(P1 + P2) = R - f(h . R . P)(P1 + P2)
>
> To verify, check that sG +f(h . R . P)(P1+P2) is R.
>
> This can be easily generalized from 2 to N.

Somone must know s1 and s2 to produce s. You have two equations in two unknowns and then can solve for the unknown private keys x of the signers. What am I missing?

Comment: Crossposted with [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/70244/18298)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $k_1$, $k_2$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ are all independent variables, you actually have 2 equations in four unknowns. If you could trick a party to sign a different message with the same random variable k however, you could then subtract the two signatures canceling k and solve for the private key x.